# Blackberry Z10 Mobile Menu links not working

Tags: mobile, drop-down-menu, menu, blackberry-10

I can't figure out what is causing this issue on the BlackBerry Z10 where the mobile menu that I created for disinherited.com won't properly function as links.

The menu items won't click through to their href's or show their dropdown menus(javascript).

It works well on a number of other browsers and devices. This is just one that won't work.

Anybody have any suggestions as to what browser compatibility issues I might be missing?

Comment: It works for me. Z10 10.2.1.1925. However dropdowns are tricky, as you don't have hover option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "About Us" link doesn't do anything for me (even on Desktop browsers).

I would guess that there might be some CSS (a layer maybe) that is interfering with the click/action event.  I would suggest connecting remote web inspector to see what exactly is going on.

Did you know that BlackBerry 10 has some of the best remote web debugging capabilities?

- Plug your device in via USB
- Enable Settings -> Developer Mode
- Open http://disinherited.com in the BlackBerry browser
- from your desktop browser, open `http://169.254.0.1:1337`

You are connected to the live content, running on the BlackBerry, from your desktop browser. From there, you can inspect, debug, profile what your website is doing.

Comment: The "About Us" link doesn't have a hover for a dropdown menu? I've tried trouble shooting through developer tools, but just ran myself in circles. I am working on recreating the menu layer by layer to see where the problem is coming from.

Comment: 1. Enable Developer Mode is in the BB Browser (not the same as developer mode in the OS settings).
2. Open any sites you want in the BB browser.  
3. http://169.254.0.1:1337 is the default, but the BB shows you the url when turning on developer mode in the bb browser.
4. this site will show you links to all open tabs
5. FF did not allow me to change the html or css, but chrome did, and I could see the changes in the BB browser instantly.